# how to implement a non-blocking server in Ada?

Tags: ada

My current design looks like this

```
task body Agent_Task is
begin
    loop
        select
            accept Request_A do
            end Request_A;
        or
            accept Request_B do
            end Request_B;
        or
            ...
        else
            Do_Other_Stuff;
        end select;

    end loop;
exception
      when Exception_Id : others => Show_Exception (Exception_Id);
end Agent_Task;
```

But when calling an entry in an agent frequently (e.g. Request_A) it will become non-responsive.
Is there a better structure to make the agent never be blocked? like interrupts?

The most time consuming part is in Do_Other_Stuff, what I want the server to do is roughly:

```
loop
    Do_Other_Stuff;
    if interrupted, handle other requests.
end loop;
```

This a school assn which I can not modify the test program to retry a failed request to an agent. When the test is runing, mutilple agents will talk to each other concurrently.

Comment: There is no generic fairness feature, if that's what you are asking. Such would have to be implemented manually, be that by cycling, randomness, or priority. It's often hard work. (Not much help, sorry. Keep me posted on what you end up with.)

Comment: Would it work for you to have a counter on consecutive events, then force Do_Other_Stuff on that counter reaching some limit? (Do_Other_Stuff being followed by counter reset.)

Answer (score 5):

Note that you have a spurious `end;` in your code that makes it illegal.

If what's important is that those making requests not block, you could use a protected queue for the inter-task communication:

```
loop
   select
      Request_Queue.Get (Item => Request);
      Process (Request => Request);
   else
      Do_Other_Stuff;
   end select;
end loop;
```

Requests will not be processed until `Do_Other_Stuff` completes, but those making requests will not be blocked by putting a request on the queue.

Using a queue would also allow you to use asynchronous transfer of control to give requests priority over `Do_Other_Stuff`:

```
loop
   select
      Request_Queue.Get (Item => Request);
      Process (Request => Request);
   then abort
      Do_Other_Stuff;
   end select;
end loop;
```

`Do_Other_Stuff` would then need to be abortable, and able to pick up from where it left off the next time it runs. But it would be better if `Do_Other_Stuff` could be moved into another task as Holsti suggested.

Finally, if you can't move `Do_Other_Stuff` to another task, and you can't abort it, you may need to break it into shorter parts:

```
loop
   Do_Some_Stuff;
   Handle_Requests;
   Do_Some_More_Stuff;
   Handle_Requests;
   ..
end loop;
```

Again, this is easier with a queue, since `accept` statements can't go in a subprogram.

Answer (score 4):

Move the Do_Other_Stuff to another task, that is, divide your Agent_Task into two tasks.

How difficult that is depends on how much communication (data flow) there is between Do_Other_Stuff and the actions for Request_A and Request_B. If Do_Other_Stuff is moved to its own task, that task has to communicate with the original Agent_Task is some way, by rendez-vous or protected objects. If Do_Other_Stuff is a long computation that has some inputs and some outputs, you might add two entries to Agent_Task, one to provide the inputs to the Other_Stuff task, and another to receive the outputs from the Other_Stuff task.